# Shell Scripting - Array iteration not working correctly - Nested for loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, nested

So, I have two arrays:

```
arr1=("A" "C" "E")
arr2=("B" "D" "F")
```

I have nested loops like this:

```
 for i in $(seq 1 $numberOfYears); 
    do
        echo "$i"
        for j in "${arr1[@]}";
            do
                echo ${arr1[j]} <---Keeps printing "A" 
                echo ${arr2[j]} <---Keeps printing "B" 
            done
    done
```

New to programmatic shell scripting. What would cause the inner for loop to correctly iterate through `array1`
when you reference the element like this:  `$j`  but not like this `${arr1[j]}` and `${arr2[j]}` ..? In all of
my reading/searching, this should correctly iterate through both arrays.

My expected results:

**Expected**

```
 1ABCDEF
 2ABCDEF
 3ABCDEF
```

**Actual**

```
 1ABABAB
 2ABABAB
 3ABABAB
```

If I change `${arr1[j]}` to `$j` it works fine, but I need to get the elements of arr2 as well, so I have to get it like `${arr2[j]}`.

Comment: You are probably looking for `for j in "${!arr1[@]}"...`.

Comment: Maybe associative array would work better? `declare -A arr=([A]=B [C]=D [E]=F); for k in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo $k ${arr[$k]} ; done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping over the *values* of the array.

You can loop over the keys if you want, using `"${!arr1[@]}"` (add the `!`):

```
for i in $(seq 1 $numberOfYears); 
do
    echo "$i"
    for j in "${!arr1[@]}";
    do
        echo ${arr1[j]}
        echo ${arr2[j]}
    done
done
```

Otherwise, you are expanding parameters like `${arr1["A"]}`, and since these keys are not defined, you get the first element of the array.

As an aside, you can also use a different style of loop to iterate over numeric keys:

```
for (( i = 0; i <= numberOfYears; ++i ))
do
  echo "$i"
  for (( j = 0; j < ${#arr1[@]}; ++j ))
  do
    echo "${arr1[j]}"
    echo "${arr2[j]}"
  done
done
```